# Postgres 12 PG_Squeeze dropping Kafka slots whilst running ad-hoc, is this normal behaviour?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-squeeze

I am using postgresql 12 and also utilize Kafka, we have 4 slots allocated via our postgresql.conf

max_replication_slots = 4

However we only use 3 slots for Kafka for each connector, when I run

```
select * from pg_replication_slots there are 3 rows returned.
```

```
postgres=# select * from pg_replication_slots;
   slot_name    |  plugin  | slot_type | datoid | database | temporary | active | active_pid | xmin | catalog_xmin |  restart_lsn  | confirmed_flush_lsn 
----------------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+------------+------+--------------+---------------+---------------------
 debeziumGames  | wal2json | logical   |  20957 | games    | f         | t      |      92927 |      |    761255395 | 15AC/3C258938 | 15AC/3C2E9328
 debeziumPrices | wal2json | logical   |  16403 | prices   | f         | t      |      91550 |      |    761255395 | 15AC/3C258938 | 15AC/3C345B78
 debeziumMarkets| wal2json | logical   |  21716 | markets  | f         | t      |     100760 |      |    761255395 | 15AC/3C258938 | 15AC/3C346970
(3 rows)
```

The question I have which I am unable to find on the pg_squeeze documentation on github is when I run the following ad-hoc the Kafka slots get dropped as well.

```
SELECT squeeze.squeeze_table('public', 'play', null, null, null);
```

The above query can run pg_squeeze ad-hoc however with 4 slots being configured in the postgres config and only 3 in use there should be 1 remaining which in theory should be used by pg_squeeze?

Is this expected behaviour with the slots dropping.

Updated:

Looking in the postgres log, I see at the time of running the select statement above for pg_squeeze to trigger an ad-hoc run in the postgres log I see:

```
select pg_drop_replication_slot('debeziumGames');
select pg_drop_replication_slot('debeziumPrices');
select pg_drop_replication_slot('debeziumMarkets');
```

Note: the above slot being dropped is not even the database I ran the squeeze against. The pg_squeeze extension only exists on the prices database. Yet it runs against the others also.

Shortly after triggering the pg_squeeze command above drops all slots as above but then ONLY tries and create new slots for the 2/3 databases.

```
CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT debeziummarkets  LOGICAL wal2json
CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT debeziumgames  LOGICAL wal2json
```

Just seems like odd behaviour.

Comment: That should not happen. Can you show the exact commands to reproduce this?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe have updated the question to include some more diagnosis. The command I ran which was SELECT squeeze.squeeze_table('public', 'play', null, null, null); by the documentation is an ad-hoc run and runs against the play table in the public schema. All pg_squeeze settings are default also. How can I avoid this as when I put this in production would experience the same issue.

Comment: I don't see anything in the `pg_squeeze` code that would do that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe does pg_squeeze only use 1 replication slot? Just cant understand why it would perform in this manner. I will test on a different server also to see if it exhibits the same behaviour.